# Scala | FilterNot vs diff

Tags: scala

Given:

```
val mySet = Array(1,2,3).toSet
val myArr = Array(1,2,2)
```

> Code snippet 1:

```
val difference = mySet.filterNot(myArr.toSet)
```

> Code snippet 2:

```
val difference = mySet diff myArr.toSet
```

From above two ways of finding difference, which one will be faster for huge sets. I am new to scala. Is predicate for filterNot going to initialize new set for each value of mySet.

Comment: Please, consider to use more efficient data structures for really huge sets. Compressed bitmaps, [RoaringBitmap](https://github.com/lemire/RoaringBitmap), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Once the size of a set is > 4 then it will be a HashSet.

I suspect diff will be faster because it is implemented for diffing two HashSets whereas filterNot is more general purpose.

Comment: is myArr.toSet has any downside when used in filterNot rather than using it in variable

Answer (score 1):

Considering that we have no idea what kind of implementation is used underneath (`Set` might be `HashSet` or `ListSet`) I would be very careful of any guessing about the performance. One version might have one algorithm of picking it, next version might use a different one. I suggest that you pick an implementation explicitly (e.g. `arr.to(HashSet)` in 2.13) and do some actual benchmarks to check that performance is acceptable.

And if the type you use underneath is `Int` then probably you would benefit from using something like [BitSet](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/BitSet.html)  or other specialized data structure.